# JavaMail crashes after build/deploy on Glassfish 4

Tags: eclipse, deployment, build, glassfish, jakarta-mail

My current project includes using of a JavaMail for confirming an user email. The problem I have is that, using eclipse, every time I *build & deploy* my web application on the local Glassfish server the JavaMail crashes with the following exception:

```
Severe: java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied
at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:333)
at utils.MailService.sendEmailSSL(MailService.java:58)
```

And here the code snipped where I'm obtaining the session and which is throwing the above exception:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(
                     props,
                     new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(usr, pwd);
                    }
                });
```

The workaround I've found so far is restarting Glassfish and after that JavaMail functions properly again. The problem is it is very annoying and time consuming doing a restart even after the smallest change in my code.

My question: Is there a possibility to reset only the JavaMail service and bind this with the *build event*?

Off course any other suggestions are welcome too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can avoid using Session.getDefaultInstance.  Use [Session.getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#getdefaultinstance) and fix some of the [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: That will probably fix the problem.  Also, when running in an application server, you should consider declaring the JavaMail Session as a managed resource that is configured in the application server and injected into the application.

Comment: @jmehrens, thank you! That information  helped. Obviously I was at that point  one of those copy paste programmers ;]

Comment: @BillShannon, thanks for your suggestion. It definitely makes sense. Is there something specific to consider in that case? Maybe you have some link where I can read more about it.

Comment: Look for the create-javamail-resource command.  Here's the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/giowr.html) for an older version of GlassFish.  I can't find the current link, but it's pretty much the same.  And here's a [link](https://dzone.com/articles/sending-email-using-javamail) to some sample code.